# Fetching paginated data from API and converting to CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, api, pagination

Very new to Python. This is my second attempt working with it to retrieve some data from an API. I've had good success both times getting page 1 of the paginated results and everything coming out in proper format. But this is attempt two at getting all of the pages, and both times there's formatting issues causing things to break.

Here's my request code:

```
# making the initial request
def main_request(url, headers=headers):
    response = request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

data = main_request(url, headers=headers)

next = data['@attributes']['next']
items = data['Item']

print("initial request complete, loop starting")

#loop while next exists
while next:
    url = next
    def main_request(url, headers=headers):
        response = request("GET", url, headers=headers)
        return response.json()
        
    dataloop = main_request(url, headers=headers)
    next = dataloop['@attributes']['next']
    items.append(dataloop['Item'])
    print("page: ", page)
    page = page+1

#print results as a string to find errors
itemsstr = str(items)
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(itemsstr)

#Save results to .csv
outputcsv = pd.DataFrame(items)
outputcsv.to_csv("items.csv", index="ItemID")
```

If I run just the initial request part of my code and then go straight to converting to .csv... everything works great. But when I add in my loop to get the remainder of the data, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lightspeed.py", line 113, in <module>
    outputcsv = pd.DataFrame(items)
  File "---frame.py", line 721, in __init__
    arrays, columns, index = nested_data_to_arrays(
  File "---internals\construction.py", line 519, in nested_data_to_arrays
    arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "---internals\construction.py", line 875, in to_arrays
    arr, columns = _list_of_dict_to_arrays(data, columns)
  File "---internals\construction.py", line 960, in _list_of_dict_to_arrays
    pre_cols = lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen(gen, sort=sort)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 403, in pandas._libs.lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen
  File "---internals\construction.py", line 958, in <genexpr>
    gen = (list(x.keys()) for x in data)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Here's the first two results in the raw output that works:

```
[{
    'itemID': '1',
    'systemSku': '210000000001',
    'defaultCost': '0',
    'avgCost': '0',
    'discountable': 'true',
    'tax': 'true',
    'archived': 'false',
    'itemType': 'non_inventory',
    'serialized': 'false',
    'description': 'Shipping',
    'modelYear': '0',
    'upc': '',
    'ean': '',
    'customSku': '',
    'manufacturerSku': '',
    'createTime': '2019-10-09T13:35:47+00:00',
    'timeStamp': '2021-02-08T13:56:37+00:00',
    'publishToEcom': 'true',
    'categoryID': '0',
    'taxClassID': '1',
    'departmentID': '0',
    'itemMatrixID': '0',
    'manufacturerID': '0',
    'seasonID': '0',
    'defaultVendorID': '0',
    'Prices': {
        'ItemPrice': [{
            'amount': '0',
            'useTypeID': '1',
            'useType': 'Default'
        }, {
            'amount': '0',
            'useTypeID': '2',
            'useType': 'MSRP'
        }, {
            'amount': '0',
            'useTypeID': '3',
            'useType': 'Online'
        }]
    }
}, {
    'itemID': '4',
    'systemSku': '210000000004',
    'defaultCost': '0.1',
    'avgCost': '0',
    'discountable': 'true',
    'tax': 'true',
    'archived': 'false',
    'itemType': 'non_inventory',
    'serialized': 'false',
    'description': 'description',
    'modelYear': '0',
    'upc': '',
    'ean': '',
    'customSku': '',
    'manufacturerSku': '',
    'createTime': '2019-10-16T16:11:20+00:00',
    'timeStamp': '2022-07-09T19:41:08+00:00',
    'publishToEcom': 'false',
    'categoryID': '3',
    'taxClassID': '1',
    'departmentID': '0',
    'itemMatrixID': '2',
    'manufacturerID': '0',
    'seasonID': '0',
    'defaultVendorID': '185',
    'Prices': {
        'ItemPrice': [{
            'amount': '0.2',
            'useTypeID': '1',
            'useType': 'Default'
        }, {
            'amount': '0.2',
            'useTypeID': '2',
            'useType': 'MSRP'
        }, {
            'amount': '0.2',
            'useTypeID': '3',
            'useType': 'Online'
        }]
    }
}, {
    'itemID': '5',
    
.....a ton more results....
```

Here's the tail end of the last "item" in the single page response:

```
    'categoryID': '168',
    'taxClassID': '1',
    'departmentID': '0',
    'itemMatrixID': '0',
    'manufacturerID': '2',
    'seasonID': '0',
    'defaultVendorID': '186',
    'Prices': {
        'ItemPrice': [{
            'amount': '14.99',
            'useTypeID': '1',
            'useType': 'Default'
        }, {
            'amount': '0',
            'useTypeID': '2',
            'useType': 'MSRP'
        }, {
            'amount': '14.99',
            'useTypeID': '3',
            'useType': 'Online'
        }]
    }
}
```

And here's the transition from that last item in page one to the first item in page 2, as appended:

```
            }, {
                'amount': '14.99',
                'useTypeID': '3',
                'useType': 'Online'
            }]
        }
    },
    [{
        'itemID': '105',
        'systemSku': '210000000105',
```

So instead of the transition between items being:

```
}, {
```

it's:

```
    },
    [{
```

Is that what is breaking Panda's ability to convert the data to a .csv? If so, how could I go about fixing it? I can't post the entire results as it contains private information. I hope what I've given is enough to understand the issue, if not please indicate what specific areas I can edit so they are able to be provided.

Comment: What's the url you are trying to scrape, what is your end goal (what data you need from there).

Comment: It's a private API for an eCom site. The end goal is to be able to extract specific sales data and such, this is my learning example where I am attempting to extract all of the items and their given attributes. I've managed to get single page results multiple ways, but every method I try to work with the pagination breaks somehow. This is the closest I have gotten and seems to probably be the best method - .csv is the end goal so Pandas works great. Just now sure what I am doing wrong with adding the pages together that's causing issues.

Comment: ok, at least post the full json response then

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this error is due to the `},[{` because pandas is looking for `},{` to look for the keys that it can use to create the dataframe, think of the key as for creating a table columns. In your case, the required data structure for data frame is violated, thus, giving you this error.

Therefore, you should make sure your data object is enclosed in a dictionary `{...}` and all your data object for the data frame should ultimately look like this `df = pd.DataFrames([{...},{...},...{...}])`. Also note that, data frame is a structured tabular format, which means that it will not expand `ItemPrice` data object into 3 new rows.

```
    'Prices': {
        'ItemPrice': [{
            'amount': '14.99',
            'useTypeID': '1',
            'useType': 'Default'
        }, {
            'amount': '0',
            'useTypeID': '2',
            'useType': 'MSRP'
        }, {
            'amount': '14.99',
            'useTypeID': '3',
            'useType': 'Online'
        }]
    }
```

These `ItemPrice` data will be treated as a row data for column/key `Prices`. If you wanted to expand your `ItemPrice` into new rows item, then you should duplicate the rest of your data so that your data structure can go from semi-structured to structured. Also note that you don't have to use data frame to output your data into `csv` file. There are better and efficient ways to write your data into `csv`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes I am aware the ItemPrice data is currently not correct, I was going to worry about that later haha.

Could you point me to a tutorial or documentation on how to enclose my data in a dictionary? As I stated, I am VERY new to Python so I am learning as I go. I'm honestly not sure what that means... lol

You mention there's a better and more efficient way to go about it... I'm open to that as well?

Comment: @NewfieTechie From reading your code, I believe `data['Item']` has this structure `[{...},{...},...{...}]`. In Python `[...]`, this is call a list and `{...}` is call a dictionary. A list and dictionary in Python is mutable. I am suspecting that `items.append(dataloop['Item'])` in your while-loop is where the problem lies because `items = data['Item']` is currently a list with dictionary objects nested within. Using `append` (a list method) will append  whatever object in the `dataloop['Item']` to `data['Item']`. This means appending gives you `[{...},{...},...{...}, [{...},{...},...{...}]]`

Comment: So, to resolve your current issue, it is better to "spread" your `dataloop['Item']` into individual dictionary object, then append them one-by-one into your `items`. If you are familiar with JS or TS, this is like using the spread operator `...`.

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct. Though trying to google for a resource to learn how to get all the dictionary items into one list, yields little useful information. Do you happen to know of a resource that I can follow along with to learn how to code this correctly?

Comment: If I am working in Python to output the collected data to `csv`, I will be taking each `items` to collect all `keys` object as a header and create a new `csv` file first, then process (cleaning, transforming, etc.) all collected data 1-by-1 in a loop and uses `,` comma as a separator for all items in the "row" based on the header sequence, make the data with comma separator as a string object and output to the `csv` file created earlier from the header.

Comment: @NewfieTechie I am not aware of any specific resources that can help you on your issue, but you can try reading Wes Mckinney books since he is `Pandas` creator. His book should help you to better use pandas for data work.

Comment: @NewfieTechie my apology, I think I am now understanding your comment. To append dictionary object to `items` you can do a for loop. For example, ```for data in dataloop['Item']: items.append(data)```. This will take the object (in your case, dictionary object) out of the list object and append it to the previously created list object `items`.